# How to set selected value of an asp:dropdownlist in a AspxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I checked around for a solution to this and the solutions I have found use a SqlDataSource, but I am not populating it that way. I have the items hardcoded in the html, and the grid is binded to a dataset.
This is my first time using dropdowns in any type of grid and I am getting confused. I tried using the ComboBoxColumn in the item template but was having major issues on trying to find the combobox control, so I went with the normal asp:DropDownList. Incase you're wondering, I can't even find that control without it returning null.

So as the grid gets populated I need to set the selected value of the dropdowns.

The markup is

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="xgvEdit" runat="server" Width="100%">
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="roleID" Caption="ID" Visible="false"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="modulID" Caption="Document/UseCase (Right Object)">
        <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="right_level" Caption="Right Level">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddRightLevel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                <asp:ListItem Text="No Right" Value="0" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Read" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Write" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Execute" Value="3" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="comments" Caption="Comments">
        <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Are you trying to find these controls in client-side script or server-side on postback?

Comment: I was trying to find them on server side in the code behind, I tried using FindControl, FindEditFormTemplateControl and still no dice. That's why I have it set up the way I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that this is custom GridView which inherits `asp:GridView`. You need to add event

```
OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound"
```

In Code behind:

```
    protected void ProductGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
            return;


       DropDownList ddl= e.Row.FindControl("ddRightLevel") as DropDownList;
       //do stuff
     }
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and always threw a null value. The grid view is devexpress gridview. The main problem is setting the selected value in the drop down from a dataset.

Comment: @Chris Try ItemTemplate instead of DataItemTemplate

Comment: And that should populate the dropdowns in the rows of the grid?

Comment: @Chris check if this data grid have OnItemBound event, if yes do this in the event. I can't figure out anything else

Comment: I was able to find the dropdownlist control in the devexpress gridview, my column was wrong should have been GridViewDataTextColumn and not GridViewDataColumn. Now, I just gotta find the correct way to set the selected value of the dropdownlists from a dataset. Any idea's? I seen a couple ways but none worked.

Comment: @Chris you first need to set dataSource of the dropdown to be equal to the DataSet, after that DataBind() the dropdown ! After that in RowDataBound you set the SelectedItem value.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around with me on this. I got it figured out. I am able to set the selected values of the dropdownlists by using a foreach loop against the dataset and set the values that way.

Comment: @Chris good you can accept the answer and finish with this question :) good luck with your project